# Vuetify.js: Position two <v-flex> elements centrally inside <v-layout>

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a `<v-layout>` containing two `<v-flex>` elements:

```
<v-layout row wrap align-center>
  <v-flex>
    <v-text-field
      value="search"
      style="float:left">
    </v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex>
    <v-btn><v-icon>search</v-icon></v-btn>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Right now the elements are aligned to the left [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KqQR.png). I wish them to be aligned centrally (as the main image and the two gray buttons in the picture linked above).
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap both elements inside another `v-layout > v-flex` and use the `offset-` directive to add left and right padding (building on top of @kiarashws example):

```
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12 sm8 offset-sm2>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs11>
          <v-text-field
          value="search"
          style="float:left">
          </v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs1>
          <v-btn color="primary"><v-icon>search</v-icon></v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use 2 `<v-flex>` components, they both gets the 50% `width`, although it looks like they're aligned to left but the input has a `block` display and the button has an `inline` display which results like your screenshot.

An alternative to do this is adding responsive classes like:

```
<v-layout>
  <v-flex xs11>
    <v-text-field
      value="search"
      style="float:left">
    </v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs1>
    <v-btn><v-icon>search</v-icon></v-btn>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```